# Configuring the bootloader with `fw_env.config` and `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET`

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a previously built image where the content of `fw_env.config` is (using u-boot):

```
/dev/mmcblk0 0x400000 0x4000
/dev/mmcblk0 0x800000 0x4000
```

Do I understand correctly that this tells u-boot the partition layout? That is the layout that I would like to have also on a new image.

I have a `libubootenv\%.bbappend` which is supposed to copy the layout above into the new image's `fw_env.config` (even though I didn't come to the point, yet to test if that actually worked). There are also `u-boot` configuration parameters regarding the layout that can be set using:

```
CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET
CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET_REDUND
```

Do I understand correctly, that these two (`fw_env.config` and `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET[_REDUND]`) define the same thing and that they have to match? Or does one take precendence over the other when booting so it actually is enough to set the u-boot's `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET`?
What isn't clear to me besides that is: Are these strictly defined by the bsp or hardware or can I change these variables for backwards compatibility? Reason I'm asking is that these values differed when going from `warrior` to `dunfell`. That would imply the answer to the last question is 'yes, they can be changed'. This is still a little tricky for me to understand thus, I would like some confirmation before screwing up some systems.

Any hints on material for further reading and research is highly welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the lively community support over at the yocto IRC channel I was provided with the following answer:

The two definitions (`fw_env.config` and `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET[_REDUND]`) have to match. On top of that `CONFIG_ENV_SIZE` should be defined.
The parameters can be configured as they represent addresses in the storage medium. Thus, they are not strictly predictated by the bsp.

Credits go to qschulz. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure :) !