# Patch rejected for u-boot defconfig file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

This is a follow-up of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006727/configuring-the-bootloader-with-fw-env-config-and-config-env-offset).
To patch the `defconfig` of `u-boot` (namely `rpi_0_w_defconfig`) I started the `devtool` to modify append another patch to change that file.

There are other patches from other layers (e.g. `meta-mender`) that are being applied before. But, as far as I understand `devtool` starts after applying all patches, right? I then changed the `defconfig` I need to change and created a patch with `git diff`. Then I wrote a `bbappend` for u-boot to apply that patch. Unfortunately, bitbake tells me that the patch is rejected cannot be applied. Is there something wrong in this workflow?

What is the correct workflow to apply a patch for a file that has been patched by other layers? Is there maybe something wrong with the patching order? Can that be verified?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the kernel config see https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html, chapter ''2.2.2 Applying Patches'' and ''2.2.3 Changing the Configuration''.

Another possibility is that the content of your patch is not valid : https://elinux.org/Handling_Patch_Rejects